# Nginx activate error

Tags: nginx

Hi every time I start the error while starting nginx

```
- Defined-By: systemd
- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-
- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
Dec 21 17:23:50 ferhat-MS-7996 nginx [23904]: nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
Search 21 17:23:50 ferhat-MS-7996 nginx [23904]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Search 21 17:23:50 ferhat-MS-7996 systemd [1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code = exited status = 1
Search 21 17:23:50 ferhat-MS-7996 systemd [1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 21 17:23:50 ferhat-MS-7996 systemd [1]: Failed to start
- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
- Defined-By: systemd
- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-
- Unit nginx.service has failed.
-
- The result is RESULT.
Search 21 17:23:50 ferhat-MS-7996 sudo [23892]: pam_unix (sudo: session): session closed for user root
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config is busted.

```
Dec 21 17:23:50 ferhat-MS-7996 nginx [23904]: nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
```

This is the actual error - you have an unexpected closing curly bracket somewhere in your configuration.  You need to fix that problem before NGINX can fully start.

Without all of your configs, I can't help solve where your problem is, so you'll have to go hunting yourself to make sure your curly brackets are all properly balanced against each other.

Comment: I saw this line but everythig is okey

Comment: @Burak Doubt it, not if that error keeps coming up.  This is why we need to see your nginx configuration file to see what exactly's going on.  And it's not just in *one* file, we need to see all the included snippets and files as well because *those* can cause this error too.